# setting the spinner according to value from the server

Tags: java, android, spinner

i have a layout in which i am using spinner to set the gender. I want to change the gender according to the value from the server. I get three vales from the server 0 for male, 1 for female and 2 for others.  and my spinner is as below,

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/gender_spinner"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
android:prompt="@string/gender"
android:entries="@array/gender_list"
```

and in strings.xml, i have added,

```
 <string name="gender">Select Gender</string>

    <string-array name="gender_list">
        <item>Male</item>
        <item>Female</item>
        <item>Others</item>
    </string-array>
     />
```

i have declared spinner as,

```
 Spinner egender;
 egender = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.gender_spinner);
```

and i have collected value from server as,

```
String gender;
gender = strLine[8];
```

Can anybody tell me how to set the spinner according to the string value in java coding???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,getResource().getStringArray(R.array.gender_list));
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
egender.setAdapter(adapter);
egender.setSelection(INDEX);
String gender=egender.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

By these line of code you can get your gender list into the Spinner dropdown for more info check this link : [Spinner in android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

Comment: thank you.. once the user changes the drop down value that is he changes it to female or others, i don t have to do any function, i just have to collect it and pass it to another activity. How to collect and store dropdown value in the string??